# Delete lines with select box without having an id in your database

Tags: php

I have a problem with my code in php.
I would like to delete multiple lines from a table with select box when a users 
press deleting button.

But I don't have in my database an id field. So it's difficult for me to do it 
Could you help me please ?

```
 $user_query= "SELECT * FROM user";
    $user_result = mysql_query($user_query);
    $count=mysql_num_rows($user_result);

    echo "<form name='form1' method='post' action=''>";
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th scope='col'>#</th>";
    echo "<th scope='col'>username</th>";
    echo "<th scope='col'>Email</th>";
    echo "<th scope='col'>tel</th>";
    echo "<th scope='col'>name</th>";
    echo "<th scope='col'>surname</th>";
    echo "<th scope='col'>type</th>";
    echo "</tr>";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($user_result))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo '<td><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" username="checkbox[]" value="'.$row['username'].'"></td>';
        echo '<td><b>'.$row['username'].'</b></td>';
        echo '<td><a href="mailto:'.$row['e_mail'].'" title="send Email">'.$row['e_mail'].'</a></td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['phone_number'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['name'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['surname'].'</td>';
        echo '<td><img src="images/admin.png" width="40" height="45" title="admin"/></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }

    echo '<tr><td colspan="7"><input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Deleting"></td></tr>';
    echo "</table>";
    echo "</form>";



    if (isset($_POST['delete']))
    {
         // how can I take checkboxes value and delete values ??
         // $sql = "DELETE FROM user WHERE username=...;
        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        // if successful redirect
       if($result)
        {
          header("location: ShowUsers.php");
        } 
  }
```

Comment: If you don't have an ID field, what is your primary key? If I were you, I would MAKE an ID field.

Comment: It is impossible to tell you how to delete particular rows from a table when the only thing we know about it is that it *doesn't* have a particular column.

Comment: I would guess that `username` would be a unique field, isn't that your ID?

Comment: Yes username is my unique identifier of the table.

Comment: So you do have an ID. So what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, If you have your username is unique identifier, Then replace with changes accordingly:=

```
        $user_query= "SELECT * FROM user";
            $user_result = mysql_query($user_query);
            $count=mysql_num_rows($user_result);

            echo "<form name='form1' method='post' action=''>";
            echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th scope='col'>#</th>";
            echo "<th scope='col'>username</th>";
            echo "<th scope='col'>Email</th>";
            echo "<th scope='col'>tel</th>";
            echo "<th scope='col'>name</th>";
            echo "<th scope='col'>surname</th>";
            echo "<th scope='col'>type</th>";
            echo "</tr>";

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($user_result))
            {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo '<td><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" username="checkbox[]" value="'.$row['username'].'"></td>';
                echo '<td><b>'.$row['username'].'</b></td>';
                echo '<td><a href="mailto:'.$row['e_mail'].'" title="send Email">'.$row['e_mail'].'</a></td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['phone_number'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['name'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['surname'].'</td>';
                echo '<td><img src="images/admin.png" width="40" height="45" title="admin"/></td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }

            echo '<tr><td colspan="7"><input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Deleting"></td></tr>';
            echo "</table>";
            echo "</form>";



            if (isset($_POST['delete']))
            {
              if(!empty($_POST['checkbox'])){
                  $WhereCondition = $usernames = '';
                foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $user)
                  $usernames.= "'".$user."',";
                 $usernames = trim($usernames,',');
                 $WhereCondition = " username in($usernames) ";
              }else{
                   $WhereCondition = " 0 ";
               }

                 $sql = "DELETE FROM user where $WhereCondition ";
                $result = mysql_query($sql);

                // if successful redirect
               if($result)
                {
                  header("location: ShowUsers.php");
                } 
          }
```

Comment: It works fine but if I press deleting without ckecked field I take 
warning 
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

I tried   error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); but it is not gone

Comment: Answer Edited. with an if condition.